# Exercise involving light cones and light rays in special relativity

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, general-relativity

I'm having some trouble in understanding (and solving) a particular exercise given in *Gregory L. Naber's* book "The Geometry of Minkowski Spacetime". First, let me supply the required definitions. This exercise involves the quadratic form $\mathcal{Q}(v) = (v^1)^2 + (v^2)^2 + (v^3)^2 - (v^4)^2$ which is induced by the Lorentz inner product on $\mathcal{M}$.

We consider two distinct events $x_0$ and $x$ for which $\mathcal{Q}(x - x_0) = 0$, that is $(x^1 - x_0^1)^2 + (x^2 - x_0^2)^2 + (x^3 - x_0^3)^2 - (x^4 - x_0^4)^2 = 0$ and interpret this as the relationship of two events lying on the world line of some photon. With this in mind we define the *null cone* (or *light cone*) $C_N(x_0)$ at $x_0$ by
 $C_N(x_0) = \{\,x \in \mathcal{M}\,|\, \mathcal{Q}(x - x_0) = 0\, \}$.

Further, for any $x \in C_N(x_0)$ except $x_0$ we define the *null world line* (or *light ray*) containing both $x_0$ and $x$ by $R_{x_0,x} = \{\,x_0 + t(x - x_0) \,| \,t \in \mathbb{R}\, \}$. Now for the exercise in question:

> **Exercise 1.2.3:**  Show that if $\mathcal{Q}(x - x_0) = 0$, then $R_{x_0,x} = R_{x,x_0}$.

By definition the $R$'s are just lines in $\mathcal{M}$, or equivalently one dimensional affine subspaces. Obviously the two subspaces $U_{x_0,x} = \{\,t(x - x_0)\,|\, t \in \mathbb{R}\,\}$ and $U_{x,x_0} = \{\,t(x_0 - x)\,|\, t \in \mathbb{R}\,\}$ are equal. Lets call this subspace $U$ for now. We know by a standard result about affine subspaces that either $x + U$ equals $x_0 + U$ or they are disjoint. That is we only need to find one element included in both sets and we are done. If we set $t = 1$ in $R_{x_0,x}$ and $t = 0$ in $R_{x,x_0}$ we get the element $\{x\}$ in both cases, thus $R_{x_0,x} = R_{x,x_0}$.

In my proof I didn't use the condition that their difference vector evaluates to zero with $\mathcal{Q}$. In euclidean space for any two distinct points there is exactly one line through them. Is this not true in $\mathcal{M}$? I understand, that sometimes two events in Minkowski space might not be connectable by a light ray, for example if they are two far apart in space. However, in this exercise the antecedent seems to be completely unnecessary. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition $\cal{Q}(x-x_0)=0$ is written there just because $R_{x_0,x}$ is defined only when $x\in C_N(x_0)$. Your proof is correct.